# Директива Angular ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Имеется задача по изменению роли пользователя в системе. Для того,чтобы поменять роль,необходимо выбрать её из выпадающего списка,но в списке текущую роль необходимо сделать disabled и selected. Как правильно прописать условия в ng-options, чтобы реализовать такое?
Роли задаются,например, следующим массивом объектов:

```
$scope.roles =[
    { 
        key:"administrator", value:"ROLE_ADMIN"
    },
    {
        key:"operator", value:"ROLE_OPERATOR"
    }, 
...
]
```

P.S Angularjs изучаю недавно.

Comment: какая версия ангуляра используется?

Comment: Версия angular 1.4.8

Comment: это интересно. но с помощью ng-options, нельзя сделать чтобы элемент _одновременно_ был и disabled и selected. А зачем вам это, ведь при выборе выбранного элемента даже ng-change не происходит, то есть нет никакой разницы был бы он disabled или нет.

Comment: Можно убрать роль из списка с помощью фильтра, disabled и selected одновременно не сделаеш

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет.

Может, вы хотите сделать так [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/xLqackxw/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.role = "administrator";
  $scope.roles = [{
    key: "administrator",
    value: "ROLE_ADMIN"
  }, {
    key: "operator",
    value: "ROLE_OPERATOR"
  }, ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input ng-model="role" />
  <select ng-model="role">
    <option value="{{item.key}}" ng-disabled="item.key==role" ng-repeat="item in roles">{{item.value}}</option>
  </select>

  <pre>role={{role|json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так сделать:

```
<select ng-model="currentRole"
        ng-options="role.value as role.key disable when role.key === currentRole for role in roles"></select>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.